# UNIXで $ aaa と打ち込んでも -bash: aaa: command not found となってしまう

Tags: macos, unix

入門UNIXシェルプログラミングで `$ aaa` と打ち込んでも `-bash: aaa: command not found` と出てしまいます。
`＃！/bin/sht` という初期設定？はしています。
OSはMacです。

Answer (score 2):

シェルスクリプトを実行するにはそのプログラムが**どこに存在するのか**を明示しなければいけません。
環境変数PATHに含まれるディレクトリ以外の場所に置いた場合は、絶対パスまたは相対パスでプログラムを指定する必要があります。

今回作成した"aaa"はカレントディレクトリにありますので、実行するには以下の様に指定します。

```
$ ./aaa
```

補足ですが、プログラム(シェルスクリプト)を作成した後、まず `chmod` で実行権限を付けておかないと実行することが出来ません。

```
$ chmod +x aaa
```

---

更に補足。`#!/bin/sh` などはターミナルから直接入力するのではなく、テキストエディタ等でファイルに記述する必要があります(今回の例なら"aaa"というファイルを作成してその中に記述)。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。"#!/bin/sh"からのをターミナルに入力していました。chmodで実行権限をつけるのを知りませんでした。助かりました。ありがとうございます。